# Как делать свои формы с ActiveForm

Tags: yii2

По умолчанию поля оборачиваются дивами и бутстраповскими классами, собственно как "повелевать" этой всей системой, чтобы кастомизировать поля под себя.

Comment: Ну не нравится бутстрап - отключи. Его же никто не заставляет использовать

Comment: отключить ассет? та и не в бустраппе дело как залавать всем этим дивам лейблам классы, аттрибуты и вообще можно ли верстать форму самому

Comment: Можно. Иначе бы фреймворком бы пользовалось очень малое количество людей и они закрылись бы давно. отключите ассет да. в конфиге в `assetManager` сделать `'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapPluginAsset' => [
                    'js'=>[]
                ],
                'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset' => [
                    'css' => [],
                ],` а в `AppAsset` из `depends` убрать и рисуйте все что душе угодно ..... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26734385/yii2-disable-bootstrap-js-jquery-and-css

Comment: та отключить я знаю как))). Там формируются дивы с классами всё равно, как их переназначить все, если activefield генерирует сразу див лейбл и инпут, через оптионс?

Comment: vendor\yiisoft\yii2\widgets\ActiveField.php - вот тут смотрите, есть настройки классов, стилей, шаблонов отображения для формы
public $template = "{label}\n{input}\n{hint}\n{error}";

Если совсем все не устраивает то можно перегрузить класс и изменить как Вам угодно.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: Прочтите, наконец, документацию. В ней описано как заменить используемые классы на свои как в форме, так и в ее атрибутах. Если не нравится структура, создавайте свой класс, наследуйте ActiveForm и ActiveField и меняйте методы ренедринга.